# Multiplicative structure on Deligne cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers, and $\mathbf{Z}(p)_{\mathcal{D}}$ the Deligne complex on $X$:

$$\mathbf{Z}(p)_{\mathcal{D}} :  \ \  \mathbf{Z}(p)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\Omega^1_X\to\cdots\to\Omega^{p-1}_X.$$

For $p = 1,2$ we have the well known quasi-isomorphisms:

$$\mathbf{Z}(1)_{\mathcal{D}}\simeq\mathbf{G}_m[-1],\ \ \mathbf{Z}(2)_{\mathcal{D}} = [\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\xrightarrow{\rm dlog}\Omega^1_X][-1].$$

We also have a multiplicative structure on $\mathbf{Z}(p)_{\mathcal{D}}$ under cup products.

Is the map

$$\mathbf{Z}(1)_{\mathcal{D}}^{\otimes 2}\to\mathbf{Z}(2)_{\mathcal{D}}$$

a quasi-isomorphism?

In higher weights it sure isn't. Any explicit example, if not?